# Unable to see preview and unable to see the main window of my app (when running) while using swift ui for macOS developement

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

So I created a macOS cocoa project called "test" using swift ui in Xcode 11 beta and got problems at the very beginning.

Sorry in advance if my question is dumb.

The first problem is that the automatic preview says it is in pause. If I click resume, I got an error.

So I tried to run the code Xcode generated (I changed nothing in the code.) and it build successfully. When I tried to run the code freshly build, I come across the following error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

The line highlighted in red is the `.frame` line in the following piece of code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

I'm on ***macOS Catalina Public Beta 1*** so this is not a problem with the version of the system....

So, did I miss something? The tutorials I found online (I mostly looked on Youtube and Apple Dev websites) either show examples for iOS or show examples that are not starting from scratch ( For example on Apple websites, when they are demo-ing codes for macOS apps ).

Thanks in advance

***EDIT***

I'm adding this picture, it might help:
[Actual screen when the app is running with the info of the threads section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joEQy.jpg)

Comment: Nan I can't :( My mac launch the app after builder, but get a runtime error.

Comment: By the way, I'm building a macOS app, so there's not really a simulator running I guess...

Comment: @matt When I saw the preview was not working, i stopped paying attention to it... :)

Comment: I haven't really worked with the combination of `SwiftUI`, a `macOS` app, and `Xcode previews` (I only used previews for an iPad app) but my first thought relate to how you are using (as am I) as **beta** platform all around. Why are you still on beta 1? Beta 2 has been out for 9 days! Apple will likely be issuing new beta releases every 2 weeks until nearly September. So, does beta 2 fix your issue?

Comment: @dfd By beta are you talking of mac os or Xcode??? Cause I am on PUBLIC beta not dev beta of mac os. And even if the preview doesn't work, the app should run find, isn't it. In my case, the code build fine, but doesn't run fine...

Comment: I'm unaware that SwiftUI does previews for a mac app. I suppose it might but I wouldn't count on it. Your code is simply the boilerplate from the template so build-and-run ought to be possible. You should certainly update your beta both of Xcode and of Catalina; you are behind the curve here.

Comment: @matt I will look to update Xcode if it is possible, I already update my mac to macOS Catalina (I did it last night).

What I mostly don't get is why the **build-and-run** is not working ok with the _boilerplate_ code as you say...

Comment: It looks like I need to update Xcode to beta 2. Coming back after the update...

Comment: I *was* referring to the developer betas, not the public one. In terms of release dates (which i wouldn't always go by) the public beta was released a weeks after the developer beta 2. I also agree with @matt - IIRC at WWDC they never really showed Xcode previews working on Catalina. Yes, it takes Catalina to run iOS previews, but I never saw anything but iOS devices. I haven't tried previews since beta 1, but my recollection is that you only have iPad & iPhone layouts - not even Watch or TV. And build & run should work for anything running the *beta* OS versions being released later this year

Comment: After updating to Xcode 11 Beta 2, everything is fixed!!!! 

For the curious, I have the proof that there's an automatic preview also for macOS development! Here is the picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oZCZWLIhgJD7RBJPDJtsw-KU8D60qGg-/view?usp=sharing

:)

Thanks for you're help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer:

Just needed an update Xcode to beta 2 :) .